# How to detect marquee completion in Android

Tags: android, textview, marquee

I have a an array of strings which I want to display in a textview one by one and heading should be changed in another textview after completion of every string. Also the text should move from right to left horizontally just like showing news in TV. I implemented marquee for text animation, but I couldn't find any listener for marquee completion.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ticker_slide"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
 />
```